# Prevent rounding, maintaining certain level of accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I am trying to apply a Runge Kutta method for solving an ODE. The problem is, python somewhere keeps rounding like a madman and I don't understand why or is something syntactically telling python to round everything? I've tried converting everything to `float ()` to no avail. What should I do to have python compute everything satisfying some accuracy demand?

```
import numpy as np

def fn(x,y):
    return x-y

def rk3 (y0,x):
    n = len (x)
    y = np.array([y0]*n)
    for j in range(n-1):
        h = x[j+1]-x[j]
        k1 = h * fn(x[j],y[j])
        k2 = h * fn(x[j] + h / 3.0, y[j] + k1 / 3.0)
        k3 = h * fn(x[j] + 2.0*h /3.0, y[j] + 2.0*k2 /3.0)
        y[j+1] = y[j] + k1*1.0/4.0 + k3 *3.0/4.0
    return y

v = rk3(1, np.linspace(0,5,500))
```

Comment: No, Python doesn’t round stuff when it’s not explicitly told to. If you want more accuracy or precision, you can look into the `mpmath` module.

Comment: @ForceBru A rookie mistake! rk3(float, ...) does what it's supposed to. I entered an integer, therefore python regards all further operations as integer operations.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is passing an integer in `rk3(1,np.linspace(0,5,500))`. If one changes to `1.0` all further operations are regarded as float point arithmetic as required.